# Post Images Size Change in Wordpress

Tags: images

I am new to WordPress and have no knowledge about codes.

Problem:

My website page with the problem is: http://ecurative.com/?p=970
The image size is too big and looks blurry. I need a way out to compress the image into say 250px X 350px. Tried reassigning the large and the medium image size under Settings>Media, but no results.

Comment: If you have changed the Media settings, it won't take effect on previously uploaded images. You have to regenerate all the already-uploaded-images with a plugin like: **[Regenerate Thumbnail](http://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails)**

Answer (score 0):

First of all set the image size in Settings > Media or seta customized image size using [add_image_size function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size).

New images you will upload will be right size, but for images already uploaded you have to recreate the image sizes, for the pourpose you can use the plugin [Regenerate Thumbnails](http://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/)

Hope it helps.